# Sencha Touch fireEvent

Tags: events, sencha-touch, listener

I have a main panel that is comprised of sub panels and I would like to fire an event in the main panel and listen to it on the sub panel.

I can fire the event within the subpanel and everything works but i can't seem the fire the event from the main panel.

My namespace for the sub panel is "test.testCard" and I've tried to fire the event on it with no success.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function() {
        var mainPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            listeners: {
                'mycustomevent': function() {
                    alert('event fired!');
                }
            },

            items: [
                {
                    items: [
                        {
                            html: 'My inner panel'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Click me!',
                            handler: function() {
                                mainPanel.fireEvent('mycustomevent', this);
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

You can see that I am creating a reference to `mainPanel` and then referencing it later in my code in the button handler, where I then call fireEvent with my custom event. Then in my `mainPanel`, I am adding a listener for `mycustomevent`.

And as previously noted, it is best to post on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/), as you will get a much faster response.